# Bootstrap button is overlapping text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a card/grid layout using wells in bootstrap. My problem is that the button needs to always be positioned on the bottom of the well at all times with the well having a fixed height. The button is at the bottom but is also overlapping the text.

```css
body {
  background-color: #5C67B6;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.btn-purple {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5C67B6;
  border-color: #5C67B6;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -140px;
}

.btn-purple:hover,
.btn-purple:focus,
.btn-purple:active,
.btn-purple.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-purple {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4b5496;
  border-color: #4b5496;
}

.customClass {
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.well {
  min-height: 280px;
  height: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container content-sm customClass">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="well">
        <img class="center-block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test123</h3> <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Join server!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to click show full page. The button is overlapping some of the text. What would I need to do to make it so where the text positions itself so where it avoids contact with the button? Changing the height fixes it somewhat, but it needs to stay at this height.

Comment: On your `p` tag inside your `well` container class, Add `margin-bottom: 50px;`.

Comment: @eeya this adds height to the well. all the wells need to be the same height. is there any way to keep the height of the well while also getting rid of the overlapping issue?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want all `well` classes `height` fix (e.g 266px)?

Comment: @eeya i just want them all to look even and proportional by default, and if there's more text in the well it'll auto resize. I don't know how much text will be in some of the wells so that's why i can't add margin-bottom 50 px; to all of them. the ones with more text cause the overlapping issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted each of your `well` class height to be fixed, You need to move each of your `btn-purple` class outside of your `well` class as well. Also, To retain the look of your current layout, Place some of your css property from your `well` class to your `col-sm-12` class (parent container)

Here is a sample jsfiddle to guide you: https://jsfiddle.net/u7ecv316/1/

**Note:** I've place a `col-item` class in `col-sm-12` then place the `btn-purple` outside of `well` class. I've also override the css properties of `well` class too.

Hope this will guide you well